# iOS: failed publishing on iTunes Connect because of invalid signing

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've received this mail in reply from iTunes Connect:

Invalid Signature - A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [iCom Club.app/iCom Club] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

What have I done? I created a new certificate from scratch through the Apple Developer website, destroyed the old one, removed all references and private keys from my MAC of the old distribution certificate and added the new one.

On Xcode, I've checked if all references to the developer account and certificates are correct (they are), I've clean the project, I've destroyed completely the "build" folder inside "DerivedData" folder of Xcode...

But the problem still remains and I've finished the available solutions.

Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004)

Comment: have you solved the problem? I' trying to publish an update to my app, and having the same mail from iTunes connect. The thing that is changed on my case (maybe causing this) is updated macOS from 10.13.1 to 10.13.2, and Xcode from 9.1 to 9.2

Comment: Negative.

I still have this problem. I'll probably must restore my Mac because it has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue all day with a target app within a workspace - checked all references, added a new certificate, created a new target, etc...

I discovered that the issue was the file names used in my media files. If any of your files (media or code) have names with non alphanumerical characters you will also get this error.

In my case, my media files had special accent characters in the file names. Once I removed those, I was able to upload the files.