# Xcode invalid signature issues during uploading

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an app for 2 years with multiple updates on TestFlight. I got no issue so far but today i want to upload an update (first one since Mojave) as usual but it throws invalid signature error on my extension. My main app have 3 extensions but it won't pass today widget extension. My signatures are valid and correct, i double check them even created new ones but still can't pass the error. In addition uploading menu has changed and it asks for 4 options

iOS App Store

Ad Hoc

Enterprise

Development

I choose iOS App Store since others are only exporting .ipa file which is not an option for me.

Here is the full error message (I'm already on Release for Build Configuration)

> ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or
>   invalid. The file at path [myApp.app/PlugIns/myExtension.appex/myExtension] is not properly signed. Make sure you
>   have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an
>   ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code
>   signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which
>   override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the
>   bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode,
>   not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings
>   are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory
>   in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information,
>   please consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If any of your files (media or code) have names with non alphanumerical characters you will also get this error (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49226227/4304998))

Also you can try to change build system in Workspace Settings to Legacy Build System:

`File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System` [image: Workspace Settings]

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro! Waste 2 days on uploading and getting this message.

Comment: What can be the difference between new and legacy build systems in terms of uploading? I can get success build with all options but can't upload with new build system.